# React error boundaries with useEffect and async function, what I'm missing?

Tags: reactjs

In my `Hello.jsx` component I'm calling an API which could fail. Here a fake API is called `loader`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export const Hello = () => {
  const loader = async () => {
    return Promise.reject("API error.");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      await loader();
    };

    load();
  }, []);

  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Problem is that the `ErrorBoundary` component (not displayed here) **should print a red message but it doesn't**. Error is not "catched". If I `throw` normally, not inside an async function, it shows the red text "Something went wrong!". Any clue?

```
<div>
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Hello />
  </ErrorBoundary>
</div>
```

[Complete CodeSandbox example is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-error-boundary-forked-6lkkj?file=/src/Hello.js).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function passed to useEffect is completing successfully. It defines a function, then successfully calls the function. The effect function returns `undefined` normally, so there is nothing for the error boundary to catch.

Error boundaries do not catch all possible errors. Specifically, [from the documentation on error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html):

> Error boundaries do not catch errors for:
>
> - Event handlers (learn more)
> - **Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)**
> - Server side rendering
> - Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

If you want the error boundary to take action, then one option is to save the error in state and rethrow it from the component body. For example:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // If loading fails, save the error in state so the component throws when it rerenders
    load().catch(err => setError(err));
  }, []);

  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Comment: So any async code can't be catched? So how to render the ErrorBoundary in this case?

Comment: @gremo I've updated my answer with an option you might try

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `useErrorHandler` from the `react-error-boundary`, which do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I like this solution. Simple and efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### Problem

Basically, you have two things working against you. The first is that the CRA has an `ErrorOverlay` which captures errors first and the second is that since event handlers are asynchronous, they don't trigger the `componentDidCatch`/`getDerivedStateFromError` lifecycles: [Issue #11409](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11409).

The work-around is to capture `unhandledrejection` events on the `window`.

### Solution

[image: Edit React Error Boundary Promises]

#### Code

**ErrorBoundary.js**

```
import * as React from "react";

const ErrorBoundary = ({ children }) => {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState("");

  const promiseRejectionHandler = React.useCallback((event) => {
    setError(event.reason);
  }, []);

  const resetError = React.useCallback(() => {
    setError("");
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", promiseRejectionHandler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("unhandledrejection", promiseRejectionHandler);
    };
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  }, []);

  return error ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1 style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.toString()}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={resetError}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    children
  );
};

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

**Hello.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export const Hello = () => {
  const loader = async () => {
    return Promise.reject("API Error");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      try {
        await loader();
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };

    load();
  }, []);

  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Hello } from "./Hello";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";

const App = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Hello />
  </ErrorBoundary>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

### Other thoughts

A cleaner approach would be to just display a pop-up/notification about the error instead of overriding the entire UI. A larger and more complex UI means an unnecessarily large UI repaint:

[image: Edit React Error UI Notification]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `useErrorHandler` from the `react-error-boundary`, which do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your async function catch your exception and throw it inside a react hook callback.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Hello = () => {
  const [, setError] = useState();
  const loader = async () => {
    return Promise.reject("API error.");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      try {
        await loader();
      } catch (e) {
        setError(() => {
          // rethrow the error inside a hook this will load the error boundry
          throw e;
        });
      }
    };

    load();
  }, []);

  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Comment: You have just tweaked the selected answer and have not contributed anything to the community.

Comment: Found a bit more context on the this approach here: https://medium.com/trabe/catching-asynchronous-errors-in-react-using-error-boundaries-5e8a5fd7b971